# Debug Assertion failed error with null terminated character array

Tags: c++, string, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

Trying to do an assignment when I try to compile the bottom code and I get the following debug assertion failed stub:

File: f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\convert\istype.c

Line: 56

Experession c >= -1 && c <= 255

Several problems seem apparant with this error message. I don't even have an f drive or directory, and unless the line is being counted in the isctype.c program I don't have 56 lines in my code.

The objective is to count the amount of words that the user enters. Check for spaces beforehand as well as null terminating characters.

The code below has been fixed according to comments from other users

```
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

int wordCount(int size, char wordArray[]);

int main(){
    const int SIZE = 100;
    char wordArray[SIZE];

    cout << "What is the string you wish to enter? ";
    cin.getline(wordArray, sizeof(wordArray));

    cout << "The number of words entered is: " << wordCount(strlen(wordArray), wordArray) << endl;
}

int wordCount(int size, char wordArray[]){

    int charCount = 0, wordCount = 0;

    //counts the number of words in the entered string
    for (int i = 0; wordArray[i] != '\0'; i++){
        if (isalnum(wordArray[i])){
            charCount++;
            if (isspace(wordArray[i + 1])){
                charCount = 0;
                wordCount++;
            }
        }
    }
    return wordCount;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
if (isspace(wordArray[i] && isspace(wordArray[i + 1]))){
```

has a couple of problems. You have your brackets in the wrong spot, so you are calling `issspace` with a boolean parameter.

Also, you should get the size of the string from strlen, at the moment you are looping past the end of the string. The assert may be happening because you are passing an invalid char value to `isspace` (e.g a negative number).

Edit: Also note the next line:

```
wordArray[i] = wordArray[i++];
```

is not going to do what you want. You want to move the rest of the string back one, not just copy one character to another.

Comment: Ok, I added a paren to the end of wordArray[i]). With your concerns about the next line, should I also add code to decrease the size of the array? Because everywhere I've looked has the same code I do.

Comment: The next line will only copy one character to another, or possibly itself. Which character it copies is **undefined** as you can't determine whether the left hand side or the right hand side is evaluated first. You will either end up with `wordArray[i] = wordArray[i]; i++` or `wordArray[i+1] = wordArray[i]; i++`, neither of which is what you want. You don't want to increment `i` in this case. What you would need to do is to move the entire rest of the string back by one, which you could do by a loop, or by `memmove`. I am not sure you even want to be changing the string anyway.

Comment: I did try removing the loops to see if that would do anything. It worked by removing the error message but now I cannot get the wordCount to go past 0; The only loop now left in wordCount(int, char) is the bottom one, that counts the number of words in the entered string.

Comment: Removing the loops and changing the call parameter to `strlen(wordArray)` leaves one more problem. `cin >> wordarray` only reads one word! Try changing that to `cin.getline(wordArray, sizeof wordArray);` to read a whole line.

Comment: I tried it and it worked for me - can you post your new code as an edit? Maybe leave your original code there in case someone else has a better answer (like the code @ppl just added).

Comment: Your new code works for me - except that it doesn't like punctuation. This is due to the check for `isspace`, which returns false for `.` `,` etc. It shouldn't cause you an issue if you are just typing in sentences with letters and spaces.

Comment: It's giving me problems buddy, I can't get it to work at all. I'll see if a friend can take a look on his pc though. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you are getting this error message is because `isspace()` accepts an integer value (`int`) but operates on characters (typically of type `char`). You must be passing an uninitialized negative value which is outside of the domain handled by `isspace()`. The value passed is incorrect and the `ispace()` implementation is gently informing you of this bug in your software. The library must have been compiled on a machine where there was an `f:\` drive. The implementation does have more than 56 lines of code.

**Also...**

Use `wordCount(strlen(wordArray), wordArray)` instead of passing `SIZE`. Otherwise you will be reading uninitialized values which is bad.

Instead of `run = false` use `break` and replace the while with `while(1)`. Also this loop very likely doesn't do what you think it does. You are merely overwriting the first byte with the second one. You probably want to shift all the characters to the left.

In your last loop, iterate until you hit a null byte (`'\0'`) instead of up to `size` as this is also incorrect. Note that the string may now be smaller than `size`; perhaps `size` should not be a parameter at all...

Given these problems, here is an alternative way to approach the problem which doesn't require modifying the original string.

```
int count_words(const char *s) {
    int count = 0;
    bool in_word = false;
    while (*s != '\0') {
        if (isspace(*s)) {
            in_word = false;
        }
        else if (in_word == false) {
                count += 1;
                in_word = true;
        }
        ++s;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Should I use the !isalnum(wordArray[i]) instead of isspace()? And for the last loop, is this the right way to do it? for (int i = 0; i < '\0'; i++)

Comment: Depends what you want to do.. check for alphanumerical characters or for white space characters? The last loop condition should be `wordArray[i] != '\0'`.

Comment: I'm only checking for white space. Whatever characters are in there I don't care about. I'm just including them as part of the word.

Comment: You should be able to do it with just one loop that reads the string and `isspace()` only. This is however going on a tangent beyond the scope of the question. :)

Answer (score 0):

This assertion error comes from inside the C runtime library. Presumably it was built by someone who does have an F drive. The line number is in that source code.

The reason for the assertion is that you are trying to test character type for something that is not a valid character. The most likely candidate is the null end of string terminator.

You should not pass in the size, but use strlen() to find it. Then you will not run into the null.

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(wordArray); i++) { ...
```

Each of the 3 loops is buggy, and will not do what the comments say. You should fix the above 2 problems first, then see if you can debug the code.